# How to draw a boxplot correctly by seaborn in python3.x

Tags: python, seaborn

I've loaded a csv file, and printed correctly, but I get an error when drawing boxplot with a Series.

Loaded my data and printed correctly

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data2 = pd.read_csv(...)
print(data2)
ax = sns.boxplot(x=data2['2'])
plt.show()
```

and the formation of my datas are followed:

```
      0                   1  2     3  4  5  6  7   ... 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
0    2016-06-06 04:07:42  0  26.0  0  1  101  0  0  ...  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
1    2016-06-08 12:34:10  0  25.0  0  1  101  0  0  ...  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
....
```

I want to draw a boxplot with the 2 columns (26.0、25.0), but I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:\Python-Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2657, in get_loc
>   return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>   File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 129, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   File "pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
>
> KeyError: '2'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "E:/work/fLUTE/Solve-52/练习/sns练习/boxplot.py", line 16, in 
>   ax = sns.boxplot(x=data2['2'])
>   File "D:\Python-Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2927, in **getitem**
>   indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
>   File "D:\Python-Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
>   return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>   File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 129, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   File "pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
>   KeyError: '2'

When changing

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x=data2['2'])
```

to

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x=data2[2])
```

another error occurs:

> TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Comment: Your column name might be `2` and not `'2'`. Try `ax = sns.boxplot(x=data2[2])`. If that works, consider giving your data frame sensible column names. btw, it's clear from your error message that your problem is with indexing in pandas and has nothing to do with seaborn. I would suggest you change the question title to reflect this :/

Comment: another error occured if did as your advice"TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type"

Comment: I suggest you either (a) delete this question and post a new one about this new issue or (b) edit your question to change it to be about the new error you are having.

Comment: And also include the output from `print(data2[2].dtype)`, maybe you have something in there that isn't a number.

Comment: you are right that I was told the type of that was string..

Comment: You can resolve it using [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html). But you should first find the culprit and fix the root cause.

Comment: Thanks, it has been solved :)

Answer (score 0):

First, change `ax = sns.boxplot(x=data2['2'])` to `ax = sns.boxplot(x=data2[2])`
Second, add such codes `data2[2] = data2[2].astype(float)`